# How to stop a call of function before the option's choose in select input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of products in my select input,what I want is to call the "duplicateGammeProduit" each time I choose a product from the list,that will send the ID of this product,but what I notice is that this method is called before I choose any option,this is my code:

```
<select ng-model="produitId" ng-change="duplicateGammeProduit(produitId)">
        <option ng-repeat="pi in listProduitUsed" value="{{pi.id}}">{{pi.reference}}</option>
    </select>
```

and this is the controller code:

```
.controller(
        'GammeCtrl', [
            '$scope',
            '$http',

            function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.duplicateGammeProduit = function(produitId) {
      $http.get(MyURL:" +produitId).success(
           function(gammeProduit) {                                     
          //the method to be called when an option is selected          
      $scope.classifierListElementGamme(gammeProduit.listElementGamme);
           gammeProduit.id = null
             ....
            $scope.finalOperationsList = gammeProduit.listElementGamme;
          });
       }

  $scope.listeProduitUsed = function() {
                $http
                    .get(URL/getProduitListUsed")
                    .success(
                        function(dataProduit) {

                            $scope.listProduitUsed = dataProduit;
                        });}
      $scope.listeProduitUsed();

}]);
```

so how can I stop this call before the option's choose,because this call 
slows down my app
thanks for help

Comment: you could try by add a validation before $http.get request. if (!produitId) { return; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.duplicateGammeProduit = function(produitId) {
  if (!produitId) {
    return;
  }

  $http.get(MyURL:" +produitId).success(
       function(gammeProduit) {                                     
      //the method to be called when an option is selected          
  $scope.classifierListElementGamme(gammeProduit.listElementGamme);
...
```

the same idea with my comment